# Use value of array in for loop outside for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the below code.  I have a form setup that has 10 input fields set up, 5 for column1 and 5 for column2.

```
try
{
    $count = count($_POST['column1']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2) VALUES ';

    for ($i=0; $i< $count; $i++) 
    {
        $sql2 = '(' .$_POST['column1'][$i] . ', ' . $_POST['column2'][$i] . ')';
        if ($i <$count - 1) {
           $sql2 .= ',';
        }
        echo "$sql2 'indside'<br>";
    }
    echo "$sql2  'outside'<br>";
    $sql3 = "$sql $sql2";
    $pdo->exec($sql3);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $output = 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
```

If I input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 into my 10 input fields and hit submit I get

```
(1, 6), 'indside'
(2, 7), 'indside'
(3, 8), 'indside'
(4, 9), 'indside'
(5, 10) 'indside'
(5, 10) 'outside'
```

And 5 is inserted into column 1 and 10 is inserted into column 2 of my database.

What I really want is 5 seperate rows inserted so 1,6 in row 1, 2,7 in row 2 etc.
But I can't work out how to take the value of $sql2 when it is in the for loop. Is this possible?  Or is their another approach I can take to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple bug;

the line

```
    $sql2 = '(' .$_POST['column1'][$i] . ', ' . $_POST['column2'][$i] . ')';
```

is resetting $sql2 - when it should be appending to it, i.e.

```
    $sql2 .= '(' .$_POST['column1'][$i] . ', ' . $_POST['column2'][$i] . ')';
```

The result is:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2) VALUES  (1, 6),(2, 7),(3, 8),(4, 9),(5, 10)
```

entire fixed fragment including fixes SQL injection as noted by @Thrustmaster

```
try
{
    $count = count($_POST['column1']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2) VALUES ';
    $sql2 = '';
    for ($i=0; $i< $count; $i++) 
    {
        if ($sql2 != '') $sql2 .= ",";

        $sql2 = '(' .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column1'][$i])
                   . ', ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column2'][$i]) . ')';
        echo "$sql2 'indside'<br>";
    }
    echo "$sql2  'outside'<br>";
    $sql3 = "$sql $sql2";
    $pdo->exec($sql3);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $output = 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that . did the trick.  I had seen it around before but hadn't seen it documented.  I got this to work with some slight changes to your code above. I replaced your if statement with the one I had. replaced the $sql2 = below it to $sql2 .= as you suggested and put a space between the . in .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column1']

Comment: my if statement had a bug - it should have been if (sql2 != "")... anyway good news and well done.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in every iteration of the loop, the variable $sql2 is overwritten. You need to "append" to the value after previous iteration.

Replace:

```
$sql2 = '(' .$_POST['column1'][$i] . ', ' . $_POST['column2'][$i] . ')';
```

with:

```
$sql2 .= '(' .$_POST['column1'][$i] . ', ' . $_POST['column2'][$i] . ')';
//    ^ Append to the string.
```

And do not forget to initialize `$sql2='';` before the for loop.

---

The way it is now, you are open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for your mysql queries. If not, atleast use [`mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['column1'][$i])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before building the query.

Comment: Thanks. I have used prepared statements before when it has just been a single entry but I can't work out how to do it in this situation where I have a loop.  Do you have any ideas here or should this be posted as a new question?