# Unable to insert a string into array

Tags: php

I have [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382444/use-value-of-array-in-for-loop-outside-for-loop/) working well, where column 1 and column 2 are setup as varchar.  When I insert a string into the form however it doesn't insert data into my database.  I know that this is because I don't have quotation marks eg "value" around my string but I don't know how to handle this in php?  Does anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm... just type `"` around the values?

```
 $sql2 .= '("' .$_POST['column1'][$i] . '", "' . $_POST['column2'][$i] . '")';
```

Comment: Yes that works thanks.  I knew it would be something like that, I tried putting "" in other places around the $_POST['column1'][$i] but I couldn't quite get the syntax right.  thanks!